# curl bad request unless direct function call

Tags: bash, curl

I am getting a 400 Bad Request response header when I use bash to fetch a web page but only when I call my function inside another function?

```
get_download_page() {
    [ $# -eq 1 ] || die "get_location: 1 argument expected, recieved $#"

    page="$(get_page $1)/download"

    echo "http://www.curse.com$(curl --silent -I $page | awk 'NR==4 { print; exit }' | cut -d\  -f2)"
}

get_page() {
    [ $# -eq 1 ] || die "get_page: 1 argument expected, recieved $#"

    echo "www.curse.com/addons/wow/$1"
}

get_file() {
    [ $# -eq 1 ] || die "get_file: 1 argument expected, recieved $#"

    echo $(curl -s $1 | sed -rn 's/.*data-href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p')
}

fetch_addon() {
    [ $# -eq 1 ] || die "fetch_addon: 1 argument expected, recieved $#"

    download=$(get_download_page $1)
    file=$(get_file $download)

    echo $file
}
```

I.e.

Calling `fetch_addon "bagnon"` I get a bad request header.

But if I do: `get_file "http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon/704176"`

```
http://addons.curse.cursecdn.com/files/704/176/Bagnon_5.3.zip
```

Which is what I expect, even though `get_download_page "bagnon"` returns the same link that I am passing to `get_file`?

As shown by doing:

```
get_download_page "bagnon"
echo "http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon/704176"
```

Output:

```
http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon/704176
http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon/704176
```

After further investigation it seems that the two strings aren't exactly equal.
When I do

```
echo $(cmp -bl <(echo "$download") <(echo "http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bagnon/704176"))
```

I get this output:

```
46 15 ^M 12 ^J
```

Ie the last character of the generated download link is ^M and the last character of the manually found download link is ^J

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the header curl was returning had mac file endings so that caused the link it returned to end in `^M`, when passing that back to curl it freaked out got the bad request header.

I fixed it by piping the link into
`sed -r 's/^M/^J/g'`

NB:
I couldn't just type "^M" I had to press Ctrl+V and Ctrl+M/J to get the correct character.